# melpa won't load on emacs windows

Tags: package-repositories

I am using emacs on windows 7. Emacs is located on a usb on a university computer with no admin access but correctly loads the .emacs file. In my .emacs file I have

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(package-archives
   (quote
    (("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
     ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))))
(custom-set-faces)
```

When I try load package-list I get 
Failed to download ‘melpa-stable’ archive.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have `(package-initialize)` in your init-file?

Comment: Probably [gnutls](http://www.gnutls.org) is missing. See also [here](http://xn--9dbdkw.se/diary/how_to_enable_GnuTLS_for_Emacs_24_on_Windows/index.en.html) and [here](https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2015/11/editor-malware.html).